# How to print something in JavaScript from an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript

I wanna add an if/else statement that prints "Only Number are accepted", for older browsers, where they allow you to add a string in a input with `type=number`.

```js
  var bttn = document.getElementById("agebttn");
  bttn.addEventListener("click", bttnClicked);

  function calculate(startingYear) {
    var dateObj = new Date()
    var currentYear = dateObj.getFullYear()
    return currentYear - startingYear;
  }

  function bttnClicked() {
    console.log("bttn clicked");
    var age = parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value);
    var yearsAlive = calculate(age);

    var html = "You entered " + age;
    html += "<br />You have been alive for " + yearsAlive + " years";
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = html;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Age Calculator</h1>

  <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Enter your birthyear">
  <input type="button" id="agebttn" value="Calc" />
  <div id="answer">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried?  What's preventing you from succeeding?  It looks like you already know how to output text to the page, so what's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to test if the input is contains something that isn't a number? You can use a regular expression.

Comment: Or you can use `age = Number(document.getElementById('age').value)`. If it's not a valid number, this will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CMIIW**

from what i see , you want to print that result from your script logic into your
div tag with ID = answer right? and you want to get only number input?

you would want to use **!isNan(age)** function to validate your input so when they validate and got not a number input , it will throw you back **error message on your else condition**

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you were able to parse int or not using `isNaN` function here:

```
function bttnClicked() {
    console.log("bttn clicked");
    var age = parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value);

    if(isNaN(age)){
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "<b>Only Numbers Accepted</b>";
        return;
    }

    var yearsAlive = calculate(age);

    var html = "You entered " + age;
    html += "<br />You have been alive for " + yearsAlive + " years";
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = html;
  }
```